# Define command for bold list-item

Tags: macros, lists, itemize, bold

I have a set of commands for producing various kinds of specific list-items, such as

```
\newcommand{\staritem}{\item[$\star$]} % not really, but you get the gist
```

All the ones I currently have can be used in the same way as `\item`, that is, just specify the item type at the start of the paragraph, and then write text as normal.

Now, I want to create a `\bolditem` command, that produces an `\item` and wraps the text in `\textbf{...}`. However, I'd like to make it available with the same syntax (so the users don't have to wrap the entire item text in braces).

Is this possible? How?

Comment: There might be more appropriate tags for this question, but I don't have enough rep to create new ones.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming I understand correctly what you want, here's one way to do it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\origitem\item
\renewcommand{\item}{\normalfont\origitem}
\newcommand{\bolditem}{\normalfont\origitem\bfseries}

\begin{document}
Before the list
\begin{enumerate}
\item First item
\bolditem Second item
\item Third item
\bolditem Fourth item
\end{enumerate}
After the list
\end{document}
```

That produces:

> Before the list
>
> 1. First item
> 2. **Second item**
> 3. Third item
> 4. **Fourth item**
>
> After the list

If you want the numbers in bold font as well, put the `\bfseries` *before* the `\origitem`.  If you want to be able to write `\bolditem[A]` then that will work with the `\bfseries` before the `\origitem` without further modification (but would need a modicum of modification if you don't want the numbers in bold font).

Comment: `\newcommand{\bolditem}{\item\bfseries}` would be sufficient as `\item` already has been redefined.

Comment: @Stefan Kottwitz: Good point!

Comment: Exactly what I was after - thanks! =)

Comment: Is there a similar "`\itseries`" somewhere?

Comment: Not quite, it is `\itshape`.  Then you can combine them: `\itshape\bfseries` does what you'd want it to.