# Is it possible to scan until the end of the current `\item`

Tags: macros, lists, itemize, parsing

I do a lot of itemize lists in `beamer` presentation which, in a later step, I want to format nicely, for instance, typeset everything up to the first colon in boldface and the remaining part scriptsize inside a `\parbox`. A common idiom I use is to define a custom `\Item` command for this purpose that parses the item text and emits a `\item` with the intended formatting:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}

\def\Item#1:#2\endItem{\item \parbox{2cm}{\strut\textbf{#1:}}\parbox[t]{\linewidth-2cm}{\footnotesize#2}}
\begin{frame}{A frame}
  Common metasyntactic variables (used to name absolutely anything)
  \begin{itemize}
    \Item foo: f*cked over and over? Well, we do not really know the meaning of this beast.\endItem
    \Item bar: beyond all reason?\endItem
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]
However, to scan the "rest" of the item's text as a macro argument, I have to finish eacht item by an explicit end marker `\endItem`, which I would like to avoid. As in [this related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1132/3751), I also do not want to put the item's text into groups of curly braces.

Is there another, more elegant way to scan to the end of an `\item`?

Comment: It's actually [`fubar`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FUBAR#FUBAR), which evolved into `foobar`.

Comment: You can use `\par` as delimiter, instead of `\endItem`, but you'll need to leave a blank line at the end of each item.

Comment: @Werner: I know. My example is furchtbar :-)

Comment: @egreg: I did consider this, but refrained from it I consider it as too fragile. The fact that the blank lines suddenly are mandatory would be a clear violation of the principle of least surprise for anybody editing my stuff.

Comment: @Daniel TeX is not a language for general parsing; it's designed for typesetting paragraphs. In order to gather some user input for processing you have to delimit it in some way. An "inner" environment, using the `environ` package, might be a better solution than using `\endItem`.

Comment: @egreg: I was hoping for some "magic internal delimiter", thinking that LaTeX, somehow, has to identify the end of an `\item` as well. Apparently that is not the case, so I suggest that you turn your comments into an answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can recreate the same effect with a `description` list and some styling. Unfortunately, `beamer` doesn't have a template for the description part of the the description list. So setting the font size to `\footnotesize` has to involve some hack. Maybe someone can come up with a less intrusive one.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\setbeamertemplate{description item}{%
    \usebeamertemplate*{itemize item} %
    \insertdescriptionitem:\hfill%
}
\setbeamercolor{description item}{fg=black}
\setbeamerfont{description item}{series=\bfseries,size=\normalsize}
\setbeamersize{description width=2cm}

\makeatletter
\apptocmd\@@description{\footnotesize}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{A useless list}
  \begin{description}
    \item[first] This is the first list item
    \item[bar] And this is the second one
  \end{description}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: +1 Neat trick, which, however only solves this particular example. (Thats always the problem with MWEs, in the end you have oversimplified...). I am actually seeking a general solution that would also work if I want to parse into more than two parts. Moreover, I need to mix my customized `\Item`s and ordinary `\item`s within the same list.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of an old post but it is possible to do this using [latex3](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/expl3) regular expressions. Namely, we can slurp up the entire contents of the environment and then split it into a sequence on the `\item` commands inside it. We can then add the closing `\endItem`'s in when we process the sequence. I think I learned this trick from one of egreg's answers.

The code below uses the `b` argument option for `\NewDocumentEnvironment` from [xparse](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse). I am not sure exactly when the `b` option was added to `xparse` but it was quite recent so it is quite likely that the code below requires a version of [l3packages](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/l3packages) that was released 2019-05-03 (currently the latest version) or later. The `b` option makes the contents of the environment equal to `#1` -- previously I used the [environ](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/environ) package to do this sort of thing. The output is the expected:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_itemize_seq
\NewDocumentEnvironment{Itemize}{ +b }{
  \regex_split:nnN {\c{item}} {#1} \l_itemize_seq
  \seq_pop:NN \l_itemize_seq \l_tmpa_tl% remove the (hopefully) empty first item
  \seq_if_empty:NF \l_itemize_seq {
    \begin{itemize}
      \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_itemize_seq {\Item##1\endItem}
    \end{itemize}
  }
}{}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\def\Item#1:#2\endItem{\item \parbox{2cm}{\strut\textbf{#1:}}%
   \parbox[t]{\linewidth-2cm}{\footnotesize#2}}
\begin{frame}{A frame}
  Common metasyntactic variables (used to name absolutely anything)
  \begin{Itemize}
    \item foo: f*cked over and over? Well, we do not really know the
          meaning of this beast.
    \item bar: beyond all reason?
  \end{Itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I have written this specifically for the `\Item#1\endItem` syntax of the question but it would be possible to make this more general.

Comment: Interesting approach using regexes to scan for the next `\item`. I have not yet tried it, but I assume it would fail on nested lists? Anyway, apparently it's time to learn `xparse`. :-)

Comment: @Daniel Yes nesting is bound to go wrong. Although, [xparse](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse) is used above the real action is in  [latex3](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/latex3), which looks awful to start with but after a while starts to grow on you.