# Entering text in the margins in enumerate environment

Tags: lists, margins, enumerate

I currently trying to create a template that I could use for tests, and one thing I've always liked is when the possible points a question was worth was listed right next to the question itself.

In the past, the way I've done this is to forego the `enumerate` package, and just manually type numbers in, such as:

```
 $(+5)$ 2.  Let $U_0 = 9$ and let your common ratio be $\frac{1}{2}$. Find an explicit formula for the sequence and use this formula to find the tenth term of the sequence. Round your answer to the nearest thousandth.  \vspace{2in}
```

But for a template, it'd be nice to take advantage of the numbering the `enumerate` environment provides. So far, I have out put that looks like
[image]
which is 99% there, if only I could figure out how to display the point value of a question.

If it's a lot of work, I figure I can always just list the point value for a particular question at the end, instead of in the margin, but I figured I would see if anyone have any ideas.

Comment: My "overkill" solution at [Enclose an entry in an enumerate list in parentheses](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70436/enclose-an-entry-in-an-enumerate-list-in-parentheses/73307#73307) defines a `\SpecialItem[\DrawAsterix]`, which places an asterix to the left of an the item's label. You could use this to place text of the number of points.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a very elementary implementation, you could insert the points using `\marginpar` wrapped in a macro. Here's a minimal example showing the options:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}% http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe
\newcommand{\points}[1]{% Print points in margin
  \leavevmode\marginpar{\makebox[\marginparwidth][r]{[#1]}}\ignorespaces}
\reversemarginpar% Points in left margin by default
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item \points{5} This is what a simple open ended question, with no other parts could look like.
  \par\vfill
  \item This would be where you could put a question with two parts.
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item \points{2} This would be part~(a).
      \par\vfill
      \item \points{2} This would be part~(b).
      \par\vfill
    \end{enumerate}
  \item \points{10} This is what a multiple-choice question would look like.
  \par\vfill
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[`showframe`](http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe) just adds a frame around the text block.

Comment: Any way to tweak this so the numbers appear in the left margin? Ideally near or next to the question number?

Comment: @aklingensmith: I've updated the example with a modified `\points`. `\reversemarginpar` puts the `\marginpar` in the left margin by default.

Comment: This worked perfectly for the question I posted! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Go to http://texdoc.net and enter the package name exam.  Preview the documentation, especially the section on questions and points.   I think this is what you are looking for.  I use this package periodically to prepare exams and quizzes.  I also teach using this package to the secondary education math teachers.

Comment: Hmmm. I'll definitely toy around with this. It seems like this could work for a lot of what I'm looking for. I'm still curious about my question, however.

Comment: The exam documentclass is amazing! While there are a few drawbacks (noticeably the amount of control I have over what my output looks like) there are definitely some benefits! Thank you so much for pointing this out to me!

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve what you want using a definition of an `\Item` command which uses parentheses as delimiters for the points of each question; this command honors the labels for nested enumerations up to level two (if more levels are required, the modification is easy):

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\Item(#1){%
  \item[{\makebox[1cm][l]{(#1)\hfill}}
  \refstepcounter{enum\romannumeral\the\@enumdepth}
\ifnum\@enumdepth=1
\csname theenum\romannumeral\the\@enumdepth\endcsname.%
\else
\ifnum\@enumdepth=2
(\csname theenum\romannumeral\the\@enumdepth\endcsname)%
\else\@toodeep
\fi\fi
]}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\Item(10) Why is there air?
\Item(20) What if there were no air?
\begin{enumerate}
\Item(5) Describe the effect on the balloon industry.
\Item(15) Describe the effect on the aircraft industry.
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's now an example using the versatile [`exam`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/exam) document class, showing the points at the beginning of each question and then the points at the right in front of the last line of the questions (using \pointsdroppedatright and `\droppoints`):

```
\documentclass{exam}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\question[20]
Why is there air?
\question
What if there were no air?
\begin{parts}
\part[10]
Describe the effect on the balloon industry.
\part[10]
Describe the effect on the aircraft industry.
\end{parts}
\end{questions}

\pointsdroppedatright

\begin{questions}
\question[20]
Why is there air?\droppoints
\question
What if there were no air?
\begin{parts}
\part[10]
Describe the effect on the balloon industry.\droppoints
\part[10]
Describe the effect on the aircraft industry.\droppoints
\end{parts}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]