# Floats lost error

Tags: floats, minipage

I tried to combine this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73983/4011 with minipage but got an error: ERROR: LaTeX Error: Float(s) lost.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}% http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe
\newcommand{\points}[1]{% Print points in margin
  \leavevmode\marginpar{\makebox[\marginparwidth][r]{[#1]}}\ignorespaces}
\reversemarginpar% Points in left margin by default
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}

  \item \points{5} This is what a simple open ended question, with no other parts could look like.
    \par\vfill
  \item This would be where you could put a question with two parts.
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item \points{2} This would be part~(a).
      \par\vfill
    \item \points{2} This would be part~(b).
      \par\vfill
    \end{enumerate}
  \item \points{10} This is what a multiple-choice question would look
    like.
    \par\vfill
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
    Some other text or a picture.
  \end{minipage}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Without minipage it works.

Any idea, how to fix this?

Comment: I'm guessing that because a `minipage` doesn't have a margin, a `\marginpar` inside a `minipage` will not work.  But what do I know?

Comment: `\marginpar` uses the `\insert` mechanism; an `\insert` does something only if it is at the outer level, not inside a box. You may want to look at the `marginnote` package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is similar to [\marginpar and \begin{align}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97237/marginpar-and-beginalign), but that question hides the main point.

Floats cannot be placed inside boxes, because they use the `\insert` primitive; the same holds for footnotes and marginpars. This is an inherent limitation of TeX.

The problem with floats is not really relevant: a float inside a `minipage` doesn't make any sense; for `\footnotes` one can remedy to some extent with `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext`. For `\marginpar` there's no remedy, because the position should be remembered.

The `marginnote` package offers a workaround; change your definition into

```
\usepackage{marginnote}
\newcommand{\points}[1]{% Print points in margin
  \leavevmode\marginnote{\makebox[\marginparwidth][r]{[#1]}}\ignorespaces}
```

and you should be OK.

[image]

Comment: I can't seem to be able to break lines inside the argument of `\points`. Could you kindly suggest a workaround? E.g. I would like to have `\points{XXX\\ YYY}`.

Comment: @Matsmath Change `\makebox[\marginparwidth][r]{[#1]}` into `\smash{\parbox[t]{\marginparwidth}{\raggedleft#1}}` (but of course you need at least two lines in the exercise if you have a line break in the points)