# grouping enumerated list

Tags: lists, enumerate, grouping

I am trying to generate a numbered list with a bracket to the right of the list to group the list items into additional categories. I am trying to get something like:

[image]

I have fiddled around with \mbox and \frame, and even thought about using a table, but I would have to re-start the list numbering, and I want to make sure that the alignment is correct.

Is this something that can be done?

Glenn

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I believe there is something called [`tikzmark`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark) which you can use to mark places in the enumeration and then use to position the curly brackets appropriately. There was a similar question earlier about doing this with a table and one of the comments mentioned this method.

Answer (score 4):

Yep, this can easily be done with `\tikzmark`. With this you

- complete the `enumerate` list as you normally would
- mark specfic points with a `\tikzmark{<name>}`
- access these `\tikzmark`s in a `\tikzpicture` with the `[overlay,remember picture]` options and draw as desired.

[image]

### Note:

- This does require two runs. First one to determine the locations, and the second to do the drawing.
- The `\tikzmark` is from [Adding a large brace next to a body of text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/adding-a-large-brace-next-to-a-body-of-text/1570#1570).

### References:

- [Enclose an entry in an enumerate list in parentheses](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70436/enclose-an-entry-in-an-enumerate-list-in-parentheses)
- [Box around a few items in an itemize environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45912/box-around-a-few-items-in-an-itemize-environment)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node[baseline] (#1) {};}

\tikzset{My Node Style/.style={midway, right, xshift=3.0ex, align=left, font=\small, draw=none, thin, text=black}}

\newcommand\VerticalBrace[4][]{%
    % #1 = draw options
    % #2 = top mark
    % #2 = bottom mark
    % #4 = label
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \draw[decorate,decoration={brace, amplitude=1.5ex}, #1] 
    ([yshift=1ex]#2.north east)  -- ([yshift=-1ex]#3.south east)
        node[My Node Style] {#4};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Item 1\tikzmark{top 1}
\item Item 2\tikzmark{bottom 1}
\item Item 3\tikzmark{top 2}
\item Item 4
\item Item 5
\item Item 6\tikzmark{bottom 2}
\end{enumerate}

\VerticalBrace[ultra thick, blue]{top 1}{bottom 1}{The first two items}
\VerticalBrace[ultra thick, blue]{top 2}{bottom 2}{The last four items}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there an advantage to defining `tikzmark` yourself rather than using the library? (It was the library I had in mind though I'd never used it before so I am sure my answer is sub-optimal in many ways.) EDIT: Is it that your marks are more node-like? I couldn't get mine to behave in a way which let me refer to anchors like that. (The documentation says something about subnodes but I haven't really understood it at this point.)

Comment: @cfr: I am sure the library is fine, I just got used to defining it and haven't transitioned to using the library.

Comment: OK. Thanks. Probably just unfamiliarity on my part, then. I saw you mentioned in the documentation and wondered if you had specific reason for avoiding the library in this particular case.

Comment: @GlennRoth: You're welcome. Please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852), and  [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say “thank you” to users who helped you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

This example uses the `tikzmark` library which was developed in response to questions asked on this site of the sort Peter Grill linked to in his answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \node (rightenum) at (.15\textwidth,0) {};
  \draw [decorate, decoration={brace}, thick] ($({pic cs:top1} -| rightenum) + (0, 1em)$) -- ({pic cs:bot1} -| rightenum) node [midway, right] {first two items};
  \draw [decorate, decoration={brace}, ultra thick] ($({pic cs:top2} -| rightenum) + (0, 1em)$) -- ({pic cs:bot2} -| rightenum) node [midway, right] {last four items};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item\tikzmark{top1} first
    \item\tikzmark{bot1} second
    \item\tikzmark{top2} third
    \item fourth
    \item fifth
    \item\tikzmark{bot2} sixth
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: Curly brackets with enumerate]