# Drawing brackets inside a minted environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, minted

I have a piece of code in a minted environment and I have divided the code the into some "blocks". I have shown this by creating dots between the blocks, but I want to create a bracket on the right side of the code to specify the block names as well. The following is my minted code and the commands:

```
\renewcommand\theFancyVerbLine{%
\ifnum\value{FancyVerbLine}=2 
  \setcounter{FancyVerbLine}{2}\ldots
\else\ifnum\value{FancyVerbLine}=5
  \setcounter{FancyVerbLine}{6}\ldots
\else\ifnum\value{FancyVerbLine}=17
  \setcounter{FancyVerbLine}{30}\ldots
\else
\arabic{FancyVerbLine}%
\fi
\fi
\fi

}

\begin{minted}[
frame=lines,
framesep=2mm,
baselinestretch=1.2,
fontsize=\scriptsize,
linenos
]{C}
// convert binary to decimal

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

// function prototype
int convert(long long);

int main() {
  long long n;
  printf("Enter a binary number: ");
  scanf("%lld", &n);
  printf("%lld in binary = %d in decimal", n, convert(n));
  return 0;
}

// function definition
int convert(long long n) {
  int dec = 0, i = 0, rem;

  while (n!=0) {
    rem = n % 10;
    n /= 10;
    dec += rem * pow(2, i);
    ++i;
  }

  return dec;
}

\end{minted}
```

And this is how I want the brackets to look like:

[image: desired output]

How can I add these brackets and the block names into my minted environment?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Hello, thank you!

Comment: Maybe just adapt [enumerate - grouping enumerated list - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/182666/grouping-enumerated-list). TikZmark should work everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I used TikZmark, but even though I specified the escape character (as suggested here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287549/is-it-possible-to-use-tikzmark-inside-minted) the document does not recognize the TikZmark inside the minted environment.