# Macro to capture until end-of-line as argument

Tags: macros, line-breaking

Is it possible to capture the contents to the end-of-line as a macro argument?

For example, consider the following naive visualization:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{myitemize}
  {\def\item{\textbullet\ }}
  {}
\begin{document}
\begin{myitemize}
  \item First
  \item Second
  \item Third
  \item Last
\end{myitemize}
\end{document}
```

I'd like to define `\item` using something like

```
\def\item#1\par{<do stuff with #1>}
```

but this requires an empty line between items to pick up `\par`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{myitemize}
  {\def\item##1\par{\textbullet\ ##1\par}}
  {}
\begin{document}
\begin{myitemize}
  \item First

  \item Second

  \item Third

  \item Last

\end{myitemize}
\end{document}
```

Looking at `\obeylines` in [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx) I thought this may have something to do with `^^M`, but I'm not sure how I can incorporate that into the definition of `\item`.

Comment: Related, but not answered explicitly: [Is it possible to scan until the end of the current `\item`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55317/5764)

Comment: You have this in `enumitem` package, with `itemize*`.

Comment: @Manuel: I'm referring to the general use-case of capturing `\item`s to do something with them.

Comment: Well, `itemize*` can be configured, it's `enumitem`'s power. But of course, if you grab them with a macro not bounded to a list you can do much more things.

Comment: `\eoldef` in OpTeX. For example `\eoldef\macro#1{parameter: #1}` defines `\macro` with one parameter separated by end of current line.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `environ`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}

\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{myitemize}{%
  \def\item##1\item{\dosomething{##1}}%
  \expandafter\@empty\BODY\item}

\newcommand{\dosomething}[1]{%
  \def\werner@arg{#1}%
  \ifx\werner@arg\werner@stop
    \expandafter\env@ignore   % to end the recursion
  \else
    ``Here is #1\unskip''\par % what to do with #1
    \expandafter\item         % to continue the recursion
  \fi}

\edef\werner@stop{\noexpand\env@ignore\space}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{myitemize}
  \item First
  \item Second
  \item Last
\end{myitemize}

\end{document}
```

Note that `\end{myitemize}` should go on a line of its own (one could also take care of it appearing on the same line as the last item). The `\unskip` is necessary if `\par` is not next to `#1` or isn't used at all, because of the end of line at the end of the item text.

[image]

A much more powerful implementation with `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{myitemize}{ O{} +b }
 {
  % do the setup
  \keys_set:nn { werner/itemize } { #1 }
  % split the contents at \item
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_werner_itemize_input_seq { \item } { #2 }
  % remove the first (empty) item
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_werner_itemize_input_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  % issue the preamble
  \tl_use:N \l_werner_itemize_pre_tl
  % adorn the items
  \seq_set_map:NNn
    \l_werner_itemize_output_seq
    \l_werner_itemize_input_seq
    { \__werner_itemize_do:n { ##1 } }
  % output the items, separated by the chosen separator
  \seq_use:NV \l_werner_itemize_output_seq \l_werner_itemize_sep_tl
  % issue the postamble
  \tl_use:N \l_werner_itemize_post_tl
 }
 {}

\seq_new:N \l_werner_itemize_input_seq
\seq_new:N \l_werner_itemize_output_seq
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_use:Nn { NV }

\keys_define:nn { werner/itemize }
 {
  pre    .tl_set:N  = \l_werner_itemize_pre_tl,
  post   .tl_set:N  = \l_werner_itemize_post_tl,
  sep    .tl_set:N  = \l_werner_itemize_sep_tl,
  action .code:n    = \cs_set_eq:NN \__werner_itemize_do:n #1,
  action .initial:n = \use:n,
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\quotepar}{m}{%
  ``#1''\par
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\normalitem}{m}{%
  \item #1
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\bulletitem}{m}{%
  \textbullet\ #1%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{myitemize}[action=\bulletitem,sep={, }]
  \item First
  \item Second
  \item Last
\end{myitemize}

\begin{myitemize}[action=\quotepar]
  \item First
  \item Second
  \item Last
\end{myitemize}

\begin{myitemize}[
  action=\normalitem,
  pre=\begin{itemize},
  post=\end{itemize},
]
  \item First
  \item Second
  \item Last
\end{myitemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can this answer be updated to set `myitemize` just like an original `itemize`? If I just wrap the environment definition inside an `itemize` and immediately save `\let\olditem\item` before it's redefined, then ````\olditem ``...''```` produces an extra item at the bottom of the list.

Comment: @Werner `\newenvironment{myitemize}{\itemize}{\enditemize}`

Comment: @Werner I added a new implementation

Comment: @egreg Question, `action .code:n` can be written as `action .cs_set:Np`?

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL They are very different: `.code:n` executes the code at key evaluation, whereas `.cs_set:Np` will store the code as the replacement text for a function/macro.

Comment: @egreg Thank you very much for the clarification, just one last question, any reason why you haven't declared the `_tl` before using them?...I always learn from your answers and you usually do.

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL Variables appearing in `\keys_define:nn` are automatically allocated, if not already done. Forcing to declare them beforehand is thought as unnecessary code duplication.

Comment: @egreg Right!!!, I have a lot to learn :)