# Aligning answer choices vertically on a multiple choice test

Tags: vertical-alignment

I am making a multiple choice calculus test and have the following code.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[1) ]

% QUESTION 6
\item Solve for \(x\): \(x=\cfrac{1}{2-\cfrac{1}{2+\cfrac{1}{2-\cfrac{1}{2+\ddots}}}}\)
\begin{multicols}{5}
\begin{enumerate}[(A) ]
\item \(\sqrt{2}\)
\item \(\dfrac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}\) %CORRECT
\item \(\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\)
\item \(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\)
\item NOTA
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

However, this produces the following. Note how choice A is vertically above the other choices.

[image]

How do I fix this? Note that I also have the answer choices horizontally aligned with other questions' corresponding choices, like this.

[image]

Comment: Do you *always* have 5 choices?

Comment: There are always 5 choices, but sometimes they are aligned with two rows (A C E/nB D) or with five rows (A/nB/nC/nD/nE)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `tasks` package can do that most simply:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[margin=1in, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumerate, tasks}
\settasks{counter-format =(tsk[A]),label-offset =1em}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[1)]

% QUESTION 6
\item Solve for \(x\): \(x=\cfrac{1}{2-\cfrac{1}{2+\cfrac{1}{2-\cfrac{1}{2+\ddots}}}}\)
\begin{tasks}(5)
\task \(\sqrt{2}\)
\task \(\dfrac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}\) %CORRECT
\task \(\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\)
\task \(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\)
\task NOTA
\task \(1 + \sqrt{3}\)
\end{tasks}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly for everything I'm trying to do. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This is the `multicol` environment - in the documentation of the `multicol` package it says it tries to align baseline, but with only one line per column it obviously has a hard time doing this.

As a workaround, add something invisible so that all the lines have the same height and depth, or at least increase the height of the first line of each column in the multicol environment.

For example

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[1) ]

% QUESTION 6
\item Solve for \(x\): \(x=\cfrac{1}{2-\cfrac{1}{2+\cfrac{1}{2-\cfrac{1}{2+\ddots}}}}\)
\begin{multicols}{5}
\begin{enumerate}[(A) ]
\item \(\sqrt{2}\)\vphantom{\(\dfrac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}\)}
\item \(\dfrac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}\) %CORRECT
\item \(\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\)\vphantom{\(\dfrac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}\)}
\item \(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\)\vphantom{\(\dfrac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}\)}
\item NOTA\vphantom{\(\dfrac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}\)}
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try the `enumitem` package with the `inline` option for horizontal lists in lieu of `multicol`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*)]

% QUESTION 6
\item Solve for \(x\): \(x=\cfrac{1}{2-\cfrac{1}{2+\cfrac{1}{2-\cfrac{1}{2+\ddots}}}}\)

\noindent\begin{enumerate*}[label=(\Alph*),itemjoin = \hspace{0.5in}]
\item \(\sqrt{2}\)
\item \(\dfrac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}\) %CORRECT
\item \(\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\)
\item \(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\)
\item NOTA
\end{enumerate*}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: My apologies for not specifying further, but I want to be aligning the choices (B), (C), (D), and (E) horizontally on the page as well. Is there a way to do this with `enumitem`?

Comment: @Guho: I'm terribly sorry: I wanted to update my my answer, and didn't notice I was updating yours. I could set the text back to its previous state, but the image is lost.

Comment: @Bernard: No worries, image replaced. `tasks` is an excellent suggestion by the way; +1.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option that allows you to tailor the alignment of multiple choices and spread them to suit your needs:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{environ,enumitem,amsmath,xkeyval,expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_new_eq:NN \calc \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newlist{question}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[question]{label={\arabic*)}}

% http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/127005/5764
\makeatletter

\define@key{mc}{choices}{\setlength{\mchoicewidth}{\dimexpr\calc{1/#1}\linewidth}}
\define@boolkey{mc}{resume}[true]{}
\define@choicekey*{mc}{align}[\val\nr]{left,center,right}{%
  \expandafter\global\expandafter\let\expandafter\mc@align
  \ifcase\nr\relax% left
    \raggedright
  \or% center
    \centering
  \or% right
    \raggedleft
  \fi
}

\newcounter{multiplechoice}
\renewcommand{\themultiplechoice}{\Alph{multiplechoice}}
\NewEnviron{multiplechoice}[1]{%
  \par\nobreak
  \setkeys{mc}{choices=5,resume=false,align=left,#1}%
  \ifKV@mc@resume\else
    \setcounter{multiplechoice}{0}%
    \vspace{\bigskipamount}%
  \fi
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
  \def\item##1\item{\dosomething{##1}}%
  \expandafter\@empty\BODY\item}

\newlength{\mchoicewidth}
\newcommand{\dosomething}[1]{%
  \def\ampora@arg{#1}%
  \ifx\ampora@arg\ampora@stop
    \expandafter\env@ignore   % to end the recursion
  \else
    \refstepcounter{multiplechoice}%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{\mchoicewidth}@{}}
      (\themultiplechoice)\nobreakspace
      \mc@align #1
    \end{tabular}%
    \expandafter\item         % to continue the recursion
  \fi
}

\edef\ampora@stop{\noexpand\env@ignore\space}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{question}
  \item Solve for $x$: $x = \cfrac{1}{2 - \cfrac{1}{2 + \cfrac{1}{2 - \cfrac{1}{2 + \ddots}}}}$
  \begin{multiplechoice}{}
    \item $\sqrt{2}$
    \item $\dfrac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$ %CORRECT
    \item $\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$
    \item $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$
    \item NOTA
  \end{multiplechoice}

  \item Solve for $x$: $x = \cfrac{1}{2 - \cfrac{1}{2 + \cfrac{1}{2 - \cfrac{1}{2 + \ddots}}}}$
  \begin{multiplechoice}{choices=3,align=center}
    \item $\sqrt{2}$
    \item $\dfrac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$ %CORRECT
    \item $\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$
  \end{multiplechoice}
  \begin{multiplechoice}{choices=2,resume,align=center}
    \item $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$
    \item \raggedleft NOTA
  \end{multiplechoice}
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

The `multiplechoice` environment provides a key-value *mandatory* argument where you can set the number of `choices` (default is 5), whether you want the environment numbering to `resume` from a previous one, as well as the generic alignment of each item. You can override individual items alignment as needed using, for example,

```
\begin{multiplechoice}{..}
\item ...
\item \raggedleft <some item>
\item ...
\end{multiplechoice}
```