# Itemized in a box with auto scaled width

Tags: lists, boxes

I would like to have an list (`itemize`) with a box around it. I know that `\framebox` doesn't work, because it doesn't support line breaks. Also I don't want to use `\parbox` because I'd have to set the width myself.
I'm doing some work where I have tons of boxes and thus I don't want to always care about the width. It should auto scale, like `\framebox` does it.

Edit:

What I did is the following: (until now) [you need to include \usepackage{minibox} package]

```
\newcommand{\ltwo}[2] { \framebox{\minibox{$\bullet$ #1 \\ $\bullet$ #2}}}
\newcommand{\lthree}[3] { \framebox{\minibox{$\bullet$ #1 \\ $\bullet$ #2 \\ $\bullet$ #3}}}

\newcommand{\lfour}[4] { \framebox{\minibox{$\bullet$ #1 \\ $\bullet$ #2 \\ $\bullet$ #3 \\ $\bullet$ #4}}}
```

So I write:

```
\lthree{Hello}{The width will adjust to the width of this line}{ but not this}
```

I know I could write recursive macros, but I'm too inexperienced atm.

Comment: Hello, try the varwidth environment : https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/varwidth

Comment: Thanks, I think I've tried it with parboxes and it didn't work, but I'm not sure 100%, I'll try. I put a little solution above, which I use atm.

Comment: give us a MWE, please

Comment: What is a MWE?-

Comment: Minimal working example : http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/minimum-working-example-mwe

Comment: Oh, I already added the code I use above in my question. But there was a little mistake in it. It works like I posted it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use some tricks from [Macro to capture until end-of-line as argument](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/127005/5764) to capture each `\item` and process it.

Below I've provided `\boxitem` and `\varboxitem` that would process each `\item` as either a boxed `\parbox` or [`varwidth`](http://ctan.org/pkg/varwidth) box (of appropriate *maximum* width):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,environ,varwidth}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewEnviron{myitemize}[1][]
 {
  \keys_set:nn { xotix/itemize } { #1 }
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l_xotix_itemize_input_seq { \item } \BODY
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_xotix_itemize_input_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_xotix_itemize_pre_tl
  \seq_set_map:NNn
    \l_xotix_itemize_output_seq
    \l_xotix_itemize_input_seq
    { \exp_not:n { \__xotix_itemize_do:n { ##1 } } }
  \seq_use:NV \l_xotix_itemize_output_seq \l_xotix_itemize_sep_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_xotix_itemize_post_tl
 }

\seq_new:N \l_xotix_itemize_input_seq
\seq_new:N \l_xotix_itemize_output_seq
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { NnV }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_use:Nn { NV }

\keys_define:nn { xotix/itemize }
 {
  pre  .tl_set:N = \l_xotix_itemize_pre_tl,
  post .tl_set:N = \l_xotix_itemize_post_tl,
  sep  .tl_set:N = \l_xotix_itemize_sep_tl,
  action .code:n = \cs_set_eq:NN \__xotix_itemize_do:n #1,
  action .initial:n = \use:n,
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\boxitem}{m}{%
  \item \fbox{\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{\strut #1\strut}}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\varboxitem}{m}{%
  \item \fbox{\begin{varwidth}[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}
    \strut #1\strut
  \end{varwidth}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{myitemize}[
    action=\boxitem,
    pre=\begin{itemize},
    post=\end{itemize},
  ]
  \item First
  \item Second
  \item Last
\end{myitemize}

\begin{myitemize}[
    action=\varboxitem,
    pre=\begin{itemize},
    post=\end{itemize},
  ]
  \item First
  \item Second
  \item Last
\end{myitemize}

\clearpage

\begin{myitemize}[
    action=\boxitem,
    pre=\begin{itemize},
    post=\end{itemize},
  ]
  \item First
  \item \lipsum[2]
  \item Last
\end{myitemize}

\begin{myitemize}[
    action=\varboxitem,
    pre=\begin{itemize},
    post=\end{itemize},
  ]
  \item First
  \item \lipsum[2]
  \item Last
\end{myitemize}


\end{document}
```

`\boxitem` (which uses `\parbox`) sets its contents in a fixed-width box, while `\varwidthbox` may shrink if the contents is less than the specified maximum width. `\strut`s have been added to allow for proper spacing around the baselines of the `\item`s.

Of course, since all items are boxed, they won't break across the page boundary.

Comment: I think to have recently seen that code. ;-)

Comment: @egreg: Freshly baked. :D

Comment: thanks, I'll try it. I also noticed that \minibox[framed]might work as well. But not 100% sure.