# How to process the body of an environment and divide it by a \macro?

Tags: macros, environments, expl3

I am trying to automate the following layout to place images and
tables using the `minipage` environment. The width of the `minipage`
environment is calculated automatically, and the design is *almost*
automatic, output looks like this:

[image: current-output]

With the following code (MWE):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% Conter and style
\newcounter{ctr}
\renewcommand\thectr{(\Alph{ctr})}
% Macro to put * on the left, no need scope (used in other parts)
\newcommand{\fake}{\par\hspace*{-\labelsep}\makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[\labelwidth][r]{\textasteriskcentered}}\hskip\labelsep}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N  \l_myenv_label_below_tl
\tl_set:Nn \l_myenv_label_below_tl { \thectr } % fake label
\int_new:N \l_myenv_layout_above_int
\int_new:N \l_myenv_layout_below_int
\dim_new:N \l_enumext_mini_page_width_dim
\dim_new:N \l_enumext_mini_page_width_below_dim
\clist_new:N \l_myenv_layout_clist

% Calc width for minipage
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__myenv_minipage_width:n #1
  {
    \clist_set:Nn \l_myenv_layout_clist {#1}
    \bool_if:nT { \int_compare_p:n { \clist_count:n {#1} = 1 } }
      {
        \int_set:Nn \l_myenv_layout_above_int { \clist_item:Nn \l_myenv_layout_clist {1} }
        \dim_set:Nn \l_enumext_mini_page_width_dim
          { \dim_use:c { linewidth } / \l_myenv_layout_above_int }
      }
    \bool_if:nT { \int_compare_p:n { \clist_count:n {#1} = 2 } }
      {
        \int_set:Nn \l_myenv_layout_above_int { \clist_item:Nn \l_myenv_layout_clist {1} }
        \dim_set:Nn \l_enumext_mini_page_width_dim
          { \dim_use:c { linewidth } / \l_myenv_layout_above_int }
        \int_set:Nn \l_myenv_layout_below_int { \clist_item:Nn \l_myenv_layout_clist {2} }
        \dim_set:Nn \l_enumext_mini_page_width_below_dim
          { \dim_use:c { linewidth } / \l_myenv_layout_below_int }
        % Adjusts the minipage width for the below part, scope \startbelow
        \NewDocumentCommand\startbelow{}
          {
            \dim_set_eq:NN \l_enumext_mini_page_width_dim \l_enumext_mini_page_width_below_dim
            \par
          }
      }
  }

% Create a environment, #1 = layout [above,below]
\NewDocumentEnvironment{picandtables}{ O{5} }
  {
    \__myenv_minipage_width:n {#1}
    % Scope \Item*[...]{...}
    \NewDocumentCommand\Item{ s O{} +m }
      {
        \refstepcounter{ctr}
        \noindent
        \begin{minipage}[b]{ \l_enumext_mini_page_width_dim }
          \centering
          ##3% picture or table
          \par
          \IfBooleanTF{##1}
            { ##2 \fake \tl_use:N \l_myenv_label_below_tl }% * on left
            { ##2 \par \tl_use:N \l_myenv_label_below_tl  }
        \end{minipage}
        \ignorespaces
      }
  } { \setcounter{ctr}{0} }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
% Common layout for images or tables
\begin{enumerate}
\item Type of questions (these need manual tuning for alternatives,
      usually carrying pictures or tables)

 \begin{picandtables}[3,2]
   \Item[note]{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image-a}}
   \Item{\includegraphics[scale=0.10]{example-image-a}}
   \Item*{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image-a}}
   \startbelow
   \Item{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image-a}}
   \Item{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image-a}}
 \end{picandtables}

\item Type of questions (these need manual tuning for alternatives,
      usually carrying pictures or tables)

  \begin{picandtables}[2,3]
    \Item{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image-a}}
    \Item[note]{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image-a}}
    \startbelow
    \Item{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image-a}}
    \Item*[note]{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image-a}}
    \Item{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image-a}}
  \end{picandtables}

\item Type of questions (these need manual tuning for alternatives,
      usually carrying pictures or tables)

  \begin{picandtables}
    \Item{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image-a}}
    \Item*{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image-a}}
    \Item{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image-a}}
    \Item*{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image-a}}
    \Item[Note]{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image-a}}
  \end{picandtables}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

I would like to automate it a little more, at the moment the optional
argument of the environment has the value `5`, but I don't always have
that amount of times the command `\Item` inside the environment, besides
I must place the command `\startbelow` to divide the *above* and *below*
part of the layout.

My idea would be to leave the default value of the optional argument
equal to the number of times `\Item` appears (here I don't need just the
below), process the environment with the argument `+b`, count the
number of times `\Item` appears and divide it when the optional argument
is present `[above, below]`, that is, don't use `\startbelow`.

I think the answer given by @egreg on [Macro to capture until
end-of-line as argument](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/127014/7832)
is in line with what I want, but, I don't know if it will be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I define the `\Item` command to just add the relevant contents to a sequence.

Then, based on the optional argument or, if missing, the number of items, the appropriate number of items is selected by doing a mapping on the list.

So, if the optional argument is `[2,3]`, first the available width is divided by two and two items from the sequence are typeset in a minipage of the chosen size; then other three items, after dividing the available width by three.

The last example uses twelve items.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=1cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry} % smaller picture
\usepackage{graphicx}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\Item}{som}
 {
  \seq_put_right:Nn \l_pablo_pictab_body_seq { \__pablo_pictab_item:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } }
 }

\NewDocumentEnvironment{picandtables}{o}
 {
  \par
  \centering
 }
 {
  \IfNoValueTF { #1 }
   {
    \pablo_pictab_do:e { \seq_count:N \l_pablo_pictab_body_seq }
   }
   {
    \pablo_pictab_do:n { #1 }
   }
  \par
 }

\seq_new:N \l_pablo_pictab_body_seq
\dim_new:N \l_pablo_pictab_width_dim
\int_new:N \l_pablo_pictab_label_int
\int_new:N \l_pablo_pictab_counta_int
\int_new:N \l_pablo_pictab_countb_int

\cs_new_protected:Nn \pablo_pictab_do:n
 {
  \clist_map_function:nN { #1 } \__pablo_pictab_row:n
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \pablo_pictab_do:n { e }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__pablo_pictab_row:n
 {
  \dim_set:Nn \l_pablo_pictab_width_dim { \linewidth/#1 }
  \int_set:Nn \l_pablo_pictab_counta_int { \l_pablo_pictab_countb_int }
  \int_set:Nn \l_pablo_pictab_countb_int { \l_pablo_pictab_counta_int + #1 }
  \int_step_inline:nnn { \l_pablo_pictab_counta_int + 1 } { \l_pablo_pictab_countb_int }
   {
    \int_incr:N \l_pablo_pictab_label_int
    \begin{minipage}[b]{\l_pablo_pictab_width_dim}
    \centering
    \seq_item:Nn \l_pablo_pictab_body_seq { ##1 }
    \end{minipage}
   }
  \par
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__pablo_pictab_item:nnn
 {
  #3 \\
  \tl_if_novalue:nF { #2 } { #2 \\ }
  \bool_if:nT { #1 } { \makebox[0pt][r]{\textasteriskcentered\space} }
  (\int_to_Alph:n { \l_pablo_pictab_label_int })
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
% Common layout for images or tables
\begin{enumerate}
\item Type of questions (these need manual tuning for alternatives,
      usually carrying pictures or tables)

 \begin{picandtables}[3,2]
   \Item[note]{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image-a}}
   \Item{\includegraphics[scale=0.10]{example-image-a}}
   \Item*{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image-a}}
   \Item{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image-a}}
   \Item{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image-a}}
 \end{picandtables}

\item Type of questions (these need manual tuning for alternatives,
      usually carrying pictures or tables)

  \begin{picandtables}[2,3]
    \Item{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image-a}}
    \Item[note]{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image-a}}
    \Item{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image-a}}
    \Item*[note]{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image-a}}
    \Item{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image-a}}
  \end{picandtables}

\item Type of questions (these need manual tuning for alternatives,
      usually carrying pictures or tables)

  \begin{picandtables}
    \Item{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image-a}}
    \Item*{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image-a}}
    \Item{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image-a}}
    \Item*{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image-a}}
    \Item[Note]{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image-a}}
  \end{picandtables}

\item Type of questions (these need manual tuning for alternatives,
      usually carrying pictures or tables)

  \begin{picandtables}
    \Item{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image-a}}
    \Item*{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image-a}}
    \Item[Note]{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image-a}}
  \end{picandtables}
\end{enumerate}

\clearpage

\begin{picandtables}[3,4,2,3]
    \Item{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image-a}}
    \Item{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image-a}}
    \Item{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image-a}}
    \Item{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image-a}}
    \Item{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image-a}}
    \Item{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image-a}}
    \Item{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image-a}}
    \Item{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image-a}}
    \Item{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image-a}}
    \Item{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image-a}}
    \Item{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image-a}}
    \Item{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image-a}}
\end{picandtables}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wow...it's exactly as I saw it in my mind, but, *much* simpler :) except for the position of `*` in `2. (D)` where the output should be `* (D)`. You can explain `...variant:Nn .. { e }` and why the `center` environment adds an unwanted line to me?

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL I fixed the position of the asterisk and removed `center`, opting for `\centering` that doesn't add vertical space. The `e` variant means that the argument is fully expanded before being passed to the main function. A central concept in `expl3`.