# Bolding a single number in a enumerated list

Tags: formatting, bold, enumitem

I want to bold a single number in the bulleted list to identity the problems my students need to turn in for homework.

I am using the `enumitem` package and this is what I am talking about.

Instructions for the questions:
1. Questions 1
**2**. Questions 2
3. Questions 3

Some more questions...

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Related: [Bold item with non-bold text](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23723/5764); [Define command for bold list-item](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1132/5764)

Answer (score 1):

Try this new command version.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand{\itembf}{\item[\stepcounter{enumi}\textbf{\arabic{enumi}.}]}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Question 1
\itembf Question 2
\item Question 3
\itembf Question 4
\item Question 5
\itembf Question 6

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not `\refstepcounter`?

Comment: Quoting from the LaTeX2e reference manual (via TeXStudio help): "The `\refstepcounter` command works in the same way as \stepcounter See `\stepcounter`, except it also defines the current `\ref` value to be the result of `\thecounter`. "   Would using `\refstepcounter` improve anything? I'm not sure.

Comment: Try using `\label` for `\itembf` and then `\ref`. See what you get...

Comment: Bill N, Thanks for the answer. Your solution works if it is the first level of the list and is a list in arabic form. So, I can modify it for different levels with enumii, enumiii, etc. and using different list types: roman, alpha, etc. It will work, so thanks for the solution!!!!!!

Comment: Bill N., a quick follow up. I am also using the inline list from the enumitem package, so how would I bold a single number in an inline list? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following works with/without [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem), but only pertains to the first level of enumeration:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{enumitem}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\bolditem}{{%
  \renewcommand\labelenumi{\bfseries\arabic{enumi}.}% Update label to bold
  \item\leavevmode% Set item
  \xdef\@currentlabel{\@currentlabel}% Preserve label (for cross-reference purposes)
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Before the list
\begin{enumerate}
  \item First item
  \bolditem Second item
  \item Third item
  \bolditem Fourth item
\end{enumerate}
After the list
\end{document}
```

`\bolditem` temporarily redefines the way the enumeration label is printed, then sets a regular `\item` and reverts back to the default definition.

Comment: `\bolditem \label{x} Second item` and `\bolditem \label{x}Second item` will produce different results