# color an item in an enumerated list

Tags: color, enumerate, enumitem

I have an enumerated list, for which I'm using `enumitem` because I want to *resume* the enumeration, and one item is rendered in a faded color using `xcolor`

```
\usepakage{enumitem, xcolor}
% ...
\begin{enumerate}
\item First.
\end{enumerate}
other stuff
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\item Second.
\item \textcolor{gray}{Third.}
\item Fourth.
\end{enumerate}
```

I'd like to have the label of "Third." rendered in the same faded color, and because I've seen [Bolding a single number in a enumerated list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267952/bolding-a-single-number-in-a-enumerated-list) I defined

```
newcommand{\fadeditem}{\item[\stepcounter{enumi}\textcolor{gray}{\arabic{enumi}.}]}
```

and it works (it's not general, but it works) but now it's not enough... I realize that what I want is a command that takes care also
of the item text

What I have now

```
\fadeditem \textcolor{gray}{Bla bla bla.}
```

What I would like

```
\itemcolor{gray} Bla bla bla.
```

*Addendum #1*

David Carlisle, in a comment, suggested

```
\newcommand\itemcolor[1]{\fadeditem{#1}\textcolor{#1}}
```

and this deals with my task of today, writing optional questions in a list of questions.

An open part of the question is then a generalization of the problem,
defining an `\itemcolor{somecolor}` command that just works in any (in most?) lists...

Comment: `\newcommand\itemcolor{\fadeditem\textcolor{gray}}`  if you don't want to specify the color or `\newcommand\itemcolor[1]{\fadeditem{#1}\textcolor{#1}}` and make `\fadeditem` take the colour as argument if you do.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I had not realized that the item body is a group.  With your suggestion I can get together a working solution, thank you very much.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes More typing, less elegant

Comment: An item body is not a group, but I copied your use of `\textcolor` which goups its argument.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I had a moment of wishful thinking... of course you're correct and I'm wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDITED to limit the scope of the renewed `\item` to the newly defined `cenumerate` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem, xcolor}
\let\svitem\item
\newenvironment{cenumerate}[1][\relax]{\renewcommand\item[1][black]{\color{##1}\svitem}
  \ifx\relax#1\enumerate\else\enumerate[#1]\fi}{\endenumerate}
\begin{document}
\begin{cenumerate}
\item First.
\end{cenumerate}
other stuff
\begin{cenumerate}[resume]
\item Second.
\item[gray] Third.
\item Fourth.
\item[red][*] Star item.
\end{cenumerate}
\begin{description}
\item[Rayleigh Quotient] Choose an appropriate shape function
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

More simply without redefining `\item`, but with a little extra typing, just invoke `\color` in a group, as needed, to get the same result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem, xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item First.
\end{enumerate}
other stuff
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\item Second.
{\color{gray}\item Third.}
\item Fourth.
{\color{red}\item[*] Star item.}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Let's say that later you have `\begin{description}\item[Rayleigh Quotient] Choose an appropriate shape function, ...`

Comment: I can deal with it `\begin{description}\item[black][Rayleigh Quotient] Choose an appropriate shape function, ... `  but

Comment: @gboffi You have two choices with the 1st approach: `\item[black][Rayleigh Quotient] Choose an appropriate shape function` or (instead of placing in the preamble) place the `\renewcommand\item[1][black]{\color{#1}\svitem}` inside a group just prior to the environments where needed.

Comment: Also `... \svitem[Rayleigh Quotient] ... `  works — it's a good answer (plussed) but it's not the answer

Comment: @gboffi Please see edit.  I limit the scope of the redefined `\item` to the newly defined `cenumerate` environment.

Comment: I prefer to use a new command rather than a new environment and a new command.  For the question as initially posed, I prefer David's simple idea. On the other hand, the question, in its present form, is possibly  _too broad_...

Comment: @gboffi I understand, though I would only point out that with `cenumerate`, there is no new command, except that `\item` takes on a slightly modified syntax to accommodate color.