# Change the color of an item

Tags: color, enumerate

Is there a way to change the color of only one item in a list? For example:

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*)]
\item Answer a
\item Answer b
\item Answer c
\item Answer d
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

I only want to change the color of the third item to indicate it is the correct answer. I have tried introducing [label=\color{red}\alph*)] but it changes all the items. Thank you

Comment: Do you wish to color just the text, e.g., "Answer b", or both the text and the associated (alpha-syle) number? Please advise.

Comment: Only the associated number, preferably not the text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How to change the color of an enumerate number in Beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425150/how-to-change-the-color-of-an-enumerate-number-in-beamer)

[color an item in an enumerated list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/381486/color-an-item-in-an-enumerated-list)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*)]
\item Answer a
\item Answer b
{\color{red}\item Answer c}
\item Answer d
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item First item
    \item Second item
    \color{red}
    \item \normalcolor Third item
    \item Last item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfectly!